# Xamarin android using bool flag from different thread

Tags: c#, android, multithreading, xamarin, mqtt

I am using m2mqtt.

My program is a remote control that opens and closes patio cover louvers

I am trying to program a preset function.  Press one button and all the motors in the system go to a preset position.

I have been working on several ways of doing it, and I have thought of one I like I just don't know how it would work.

---- Set Up ----

What I want to do is start the motors moving in the right direction.  Then lock up the main thread until the motors are done (something like)

```
private bool flag = false;

private void presets () 
{

flag = true;
-----
code to get motors moving in right direction
-----
client.MqttMsgPublishReceived -= regularMessagesReceive
client.MqttMsgPublishReceived += presetMessagesReceive
while(flag)
{
}
client.MqttMsgPublishReceived -= presetMessagesReceive
client.MqttMsgPublishReceived += regularMessagesReceive

}

void presetMessagesReceive(object sender, MqttMsgPublishEventArgs e)
{
//incoming messages indicate all motor positions

if (allMotorsInPosition) 
{
        flage = false; //when all motors have reached their preset positions 

}


}
```

Will changing the flag to false in the mqtt recieve message thread release the while loop in the main thread ?????????

You may ask why I want to lock everything up ...... I can't have them using the other buttons on the remote it will confuse the system.  So I either have to enable=false all of them or just tie up the thread until the presets are through

Comment: Consider using events to signal asynchronously to the caller of progress (i.e. ProcessStarted, ProcessComplete etc), then the caller can handle the events and change local flags etc when appropriate.

Comment: When you start the motors moving, set  other buttons `enable=false` cant solve your problem?